How to apply max-age in cache control for images in Nextjs?
I have created the following next.config.js file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
    
    async headers() {
        return [
            {
                source: "/_next/image",
                headers: [
                    {
                        key: "Cache-Control",
                        value: "public, max-age=86400, immutable", // 86400 seconds = 1 day
                    },
                ],
            },
        ];
    },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;

I am using GCP load balancer for Cloud Run Service that hosts this application with Cloud CDN enabled. There also I have set the TTL value for client, default and max to 1 day.
I am still getting the Cache-Control header for images set as public,max-age=60,must-revalidate in response headers in website live in production.
Can you please suggest what else might need to be changed?

You can configure minimumCacheTTL to increase the cache duration when the upstream image does not include Cache-Control header or the value is very low.
module.exports = {
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 15552000, // 6 months
  },
}

Note: If you need to change the caching behavior per image, you can configure headers to set the Cache-Control header on the upstream image (e.g. /some-asset.jpg, not /_next/image itself).
Therefore to set cache for all of the images you need to configure minimumCacheTTL value.
